# How do I set the accept language header when using poltergeist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, poltergeist

I am trying to added a non-english language for a test using capybara and poltergeist.  I have tried:

```
page.driver.headers = { 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'pt-BR' }
```

But that is not working.  On the server side, 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' is always 'en-US'.  I have even tried adding another arbitrary header but that isn't coming through on the server side. It seems like poltergeist's header setting doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expected that the right header to set was the same as retrieving in rails but HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE is not a valid http header (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).  It is specific to rails.

I needed to do:

```
page.driver.headers = { 'ACCEPT-LANGUAGE' => 'pt-BR' }
```